# How to create and insert div element to .ejs (node.js, express, ejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I have an array of objects and I need to create div elements while iterating over it and then render it using ejs. I'm using node.js express and ejs. How can I create divs and inject it to ejs?

Answer (score 0):

you can use in ejs like that, it's simple for function:

In ejs:

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i ++) { %>

 <a href="/product/<%=products[i].product_id%>"> 
 <b> <%=products[i].product_id%> </b> 
<% } %>
```

In js file:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('sell',{ products: array})
});
```

Comment: Dude!! You are the best! <3